# How to fill up table in MS WORD c#

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word

I need to fill up table in MS WORD from List. Amount of my rows is not fixed, and I can not find how to do it by c#

Comment: You need to provide more information. Start with what you mean by "fill up a table": Are you working with a template? What code do you use, so far, to add the data to the document, especially the table? A [mcve] would be helpful...

Comment: I have answered below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       it will add numers of rows

     string pathDocument = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "example.docx";

            DocX document = DocX.Create(pathDocument);

            Table table = document.AddTable(res.Count, 10);

            table.Alignment = Alignment.center;

            table.Design = TableDesign.TableGrid;
            for(var row=0;row<res.Count;row++)
            {

                table.Rows[row].Cells[0].Paragraphs[0].Append((row+1).ToString());
            }

            document.InsertParagraph().InsertTableAfterSelf(table);


            document.Save();
```